# React button not clickable in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, safari

I built a react app which is working fine in chrome, but for some reason there's a button that isn't clickable in Safari and Mozilla.

It's a very basic headr with a boostrap button on it. Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

```
const Header = (props) => {

  const testFunc = () => {
    console.log("button clicked");
  }

  let connectionButton;
  if (window.accountId == null || typeof window.accountId === 'undefined' || accountId == '') {
    connectionButton = <button className="bold-font btn-transparent header_connect_btn" onClick={()=>testFunc()}>Connect Wallet</button>;
  } else {
    connectionButton = <button className="bold-font btn-transparent header_connect_btn" onClick={()=>props.setshowDeposit(true)}>Ⓝ {props.balanceProps}</button>;
  }

  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <div className='header_background'></div>
      <Stack direction='horizontal' className="header_navbar header-mobile" gap={3}>
        <Image src={KangarooLogo}  className = "logo-header"/><div></div>
        <Stack direction="horizontal" className="pull-right" gap={2}>
          <a href="/#">About</a>
          <a href="/#">How To Play</a>
          <a href="/#">FAQ</a>

        </Stack>
        {connectionButton}
      </Stack>      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: each browser interprets html and css in its own way, try to use code compatible with other browsers. You can use https://www.w3schools.com/ to see which parts of the code work in your browser

Comment: That makes sense, but I mean, we're talking about button here, it should have the onclick property on every browser right?

Comment: Do not necessarily

Comment: Once upon a time I wrote a similar project with a similar problem, we just have to accept that some features are not supported and try to fix the problem in a different way